Inject service from plugin in a strapi admin page
I have create a plugin for strapi cms. It contains a service in the server part which is used in a cron job to update data. Now i want to call the same method in a page in the admin part of the plugin.
const click = () => strapi.plugin('google-places').services.googlePlaces.updateGooglePlaces();

The could compiles but is not working, it tells me that strapi is undefined. The variable strapi is the global prop for the loaded strapi. If the loaded strapi is undefined, i guess i am doing something wrong :)
I already checked some other strapi plugin and there they are doing web requests manually to there defined api. Is it really the way to go?

Well, not sure if it is the best but:
using a controller
export default ({strapi}: { strapi: Strapi }) => ({
  async index(ctx) {
    ctx.body = await strapi
      .plugin('google-places')
      .service('googlePlaces')
      .updateGooglePlaces();
  },
});

and calling it using
  const click = () => {
    const {get} = getFetchClient();
    get('/google-places');
  }

is a good solution to me.
Interesting fact is that
import {getFetchClient} from "@strapi/helper-plugin";

is doing the trick by adding the jwt token and so one, so no extra work to do for me.
